# C# destroy or disable particular objects of class

Tags: c#, list, class, object, destroy

i have a windows form and a class named testclass.cs . the below sample code is for testclass.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace testApp
{
     public class testclass
    {
       public void disableEverything()
       {
           //some operations goes here
       }
       public void welcome()
       {
         //some code goes here
       }
    }
 }
```

and inside my form i have code for create object inside a button click event
the below code shows the form1

```
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Text;

       namespace testApp
       {
          public partial class Form1: Form
          {
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               testclass obj = new testclass();
               obj.welcome();

            }
          }
        }
```

my question is if i click button1 five times it will create 5 objects of the class `testclass`.
suppose if i want to call `disableEverything` method of some purticular class objects like 3rd object, second object , how can i call this? should i use a `List<testclass>` and call `list[index].disableEverything()` . suggest me a good soultion for this

Comment: Living up to your name I see.

Comment: Destroy class being inside the class? It's non-sense even if it'd be allowed. What is your question about? Be more specific.

Comment: If you don't want to create multiple instances of this class you should place this object in Global and instantiate it when the form loads up.

Comment: Also you should learn about IDisposable, instead of making your own version of it.

Comment: @JohnyL , its like disable something(example a bool value set to false) of that particular class using their object.

Comment: You need those instances to be in scope when you want to set a property or call a method on them. There is no one right way, especially not knowing what your system is intended to do.

Comment: Guys im not talking about destroy the class object. i want to disable some features of that purticular class, and if i want to destroy that object i have to call `obj.Destroy();` by inheriting IDisposable interface?

Comment: You should implement `IDisposable` interface. Do you have some unmanaged resources references?

Comment: @JohnyL Yes! Its there

Comment: Still don't get you. When you press button 5 times, 5 objects come to life. In your example, they exist until the end of event handler. Further, they are reclaimed by Garbage Collector. What are you about to disable - it's not clear...

Comment: @JohnyL, ok ! what to do if i want to keep object lifetime until form close ?

Comment: `what to do if i want to keep object lifetime until form close ?` Store it in a field (maybe a `List`) of the form?

Answer (score 1):

I dunno what you are implement, but for unmanaged resources, you can implement IDisposable, and use "Using" for release the resources after work:

```
namespace testApp
{
  public class testclass : IDisposable
  {
      bool disposed = false;
     //Instantiate a SafeHandle instance.
      SafeHandle handle = new SafeFileHandle(IntPtr.Zero, true);
    // Public implementation of Dispose pattern callable by consumers.
    public void Dispose()
   { 
     Dispose(true);
     GC.SuppressFinalize(this);           
   }

   // Protected implementation of Dispose pattern.
   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
     if (disposed)
      return; 
     if (disposing) {
      handle.Dispose();
      // Free any other managed objects here.
      //
    }

    // Free any unmanaged objects here.
     //
    disposed = true;
   }  


    public void welcome()
    {
         //some code goes here
     }
   }
 }

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       using (var obj = new testclass())
       {

       }
 }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And where's interface implementation?

Comment: Forget about destroying objects. what i am asking is how can i get those particular objects are still alive and invoke some method of that class

Comment: if you create your objects in Global scope, they will live as long as your form is alive, so why you need to check it?

Comment: @Zorkind i am creating multiple object of same class type. not single object

Comment: Ok so make a list/dictionary/array of it in Global and place them all in it.

Comment: List<testclass> for example, you can then add or remove as you see fit.

Comment: If your purpose is not destroy objects, Zorkind solutions its a good solution, if your want to they live in all forms, you can put it in main Thread.

Comment: in global i have placed `List<testclass> objcList = new List<testclass>();` and inside the button1_click event `testclass obj = new tstclass();` `objcList.Add(obj); ` like this?